# Software to explore abstract algebra and/or category theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, math-software, online-resources

Is there any software that lets one explore group theory, ring theory, and category theory visually and theoretically that is tailored for education purposes? I'm not talking about using software like maple or mathematica but something more specific for learning and retention of ideas.

Something sorta like geogebra but for algebra. Something that lets one take some group(either built in or user-defined) and mess around with it to see what we learn at work. It should be highly visual and do all the heavy lifting.

Comment: What exactly do you want this utility to do? Show you cosets? And most interesting categories are too large to be visualizable in this way.

Comment: For group theory, Tim Dokchitser has a database called [GroupNames](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/). There is also a preliminary version of a groups database in the LMFDB, currently available at https://groups.lmfdb.xyz/Groups/Abstract/. Both will give you presentations, important subgroups and quotients, and character tables.

Comment: @DonThousand For groups and rings to be able to show visualizations of the group, show different subgroups(Torsion, commutator, etc). For category theory one doesn't need to show the entire categorical structure. The point is to learn through visualization, that is not impossible... just requires someone to have done or to do the work.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Thanks. This isn't really the "interactive visualization" I was hoping for but it seems to have quite a bit of information. I'll have to play around with it to see how much info it contains. E.g., what it doesn't show is the tables for the smaller groups and then allowing one to play with the groups such as taking automorphisms and visually seeing the effect, displaying the elements by highlighting, say, the commutator group. Treating the group as some permutation on geometric figures, etc. Although the 2nd link seems to have something to do with some of this.

Comment: I have intermediate-level skills in OpenGL. If you have an idea for graphics software, you can always email me at sjhalayka@gmail.com

Comment: It depends on the purposes, but likely [Group Explorer](https://nathancarter.github.io/group-explorer/) will be a good fit. If you want to add some coding for, as you say, "heavy lifting", then look at [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/), which can also visualise things in Jupyter notebooks - see  https://github.com/OpenDreamKit/gap-demos/blob/master/Index.ipynb for a non-interactive preview.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Cool. I haven't messed with it much but it does have some things I was wanting. It doesn't seem to let one visualize much beyond subgroups though. It's along the lines of what I'm talking about but seems quite limited in those regards. Ideally one could interact with the groups in a mathematical way such as doing computations and transformations on the groups themselves and visualize the results. I'll check out the others tomorrow.

Comment: Your mileage with GAP may vary. Most likely, you will find out that you can calculate a lot in the command line, but there is no ready solution to visualise things the way you imagine, and it has to be developed. For the Group Explorer, see also the [Visual Group Theory](http://web.bentley.edu/empl/c/ncarter/vgt/) book.